# Powershell select value from datatable where

Tags: sql-server, csv, powershell

I have a data table that I have imported from SQL which has two columns.  One is country code and the other is country name.

[image: Country Code table]

I have a CVS import of country names and I want to go through the data table with each country name and get its corresponding country code.

If it were SQL I could do this but I can't think how best to achieve this in PowerShell.  I could of course pass each country name to SQL and query the country code but there are approx. 7000 entries in the csv file.

I have the following code which imports the csv file and I can iterate through the objects within it

```
$path = "C:\Temp\myImport.csv"
$import = import-csv $path

foreach($object in $import){

}
```

Comment: So... You need to load data from CSV file in SQL Server with the help of PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute insert for every row.

```
$SQLInsertFormat="insert into [table name goes there]([columns goes there]) values ({0},{1})"

$SQLConnectionString = "[connection string goes there]"
$SQLCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SQLCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text

$SQLCmd.Connection = $SQLConnectionString
$SQLCmd.Connection.Open()
$path = "C:\Temp\myImport.csv"
$import = import-csv $path

foreach($object in $import){
    $SQLCmd.CommandText = $SQLInsertFormat -f $object.CountryCode, $object.UpperCase
    $SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

$SQLCmd.Connection.Close()
```